# map new column values based on avg of salary column in scala (convert string to int)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, machine-learning, apache-spark-sql

I have dep code in string which I want to convert into number based on avg of salary column.

```
dep code    salary     new-column
 abc          100            2
 bcd           90            1
 abc          110            2
```

new-column value is greater if avg salary for that dep is greater.

Note - I have converted all the csv file data into dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use `rank()` Window function:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("abc", 100), ("bcd", 90), ("abc", 110),
  ("eee", 90), ("eee", 100), ("fff", 95)
).toDF("dep code", "salary")

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

df.withColumn("average", avg($"salary").over(Window.partitionBy($"dep code"))).
  withColumn("rank", rank.over(Window.orderBy($"average"))).
  show
// +-------+------+-------+----+
// |dep code|salary|average|rank|
// +--------+------+-------+----+
// |     bcd|    90|   90.0|   1|
// |     fff|    95|   95.0|   2|
// |     eee|    90|   95.0|   2|
// |     eee|   100|   95.0|   2|
// |     abc|   100|  105.0|   5|
// |     abc|   110|  105.0|   5|
// +--------+------+-------+----+
```

Use `dense_rank()` in case you prefer to have contiguous ranks:

```
df.withColumn("average", avg($"salary").over(Window.partitionBy($"dep code"))).
  withColumn("rank", dense_rank.over(Window.orderBy($"average"))).
  show
// +--------+------+-------+----+
// |dep code|salary|average|rank|
// +--------+------+-------+----+
// |     bcd|    90|   90.0|   1|
// |     fff|    95|   95.0|   2|
// |     eee|    90|   95.0|   2|
// |     eee|   100|   95.0|   2|
// |     abc|   100|  105.0|   3|
// |     abc|   110|  105.0|   3|
// +--------+------+-------+----+
```

Comment: avg($"salary") gives error "Application does not take parameters". Please help on this!!!

Comment: Methods like avg() take `Column`` or `String`` (i.e. without the preceding `$`), as do partitionBy() and orderBy().  Try avg("salary").  Also, please make sure `org.apache.spark.sql.functions._` is imported.